# Laravel one-to-many relationship query with LIKE option

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have tables like this

```
brands
- id
- name
- status (default=1)

products
- id
- brand_id
- name
```

and I want to query a "**keyword**" so it should match with either "**brand.name**" or "**product.name**".
Here is my current query which works fine with "**brand.name**", but I am not sure how to use this with "**product.name**".

```
Brand::where('status', 1)->where('name', 'like', "%{$keyword}%")->get()->sortBy('name')
```

It is one-to-many relationship as one brand can have many products.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If you only want query for product name then just make a model for Products and query will be similar like you've made for brand.

Comment: I want a query that lists brands only. But it needs to look the keyword into product name aswell. I have the model set up already for both but I am not very good with eloquent methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `whereHas` to search in the related models. assuming the `hasMany` relation name is `products`.

```
Brand::where('status', 1)
     ->where(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
         $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$keyword}%")
               ->orWhereHas('products', function ($query) use ($keyword) {
                   $query->where('name','LIKE',"%{$keyword}%");
               });
     })
     ->get();
```

Useful reading: [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: Thank You. Got it working. I should bookmark this link :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
Brand::leftJoin('products', 'brands.id', '=', 'products.brand_id')
->where('status', 1)
->whereRaw('brands.name like "%'.$keyword.'%" OR products.name like "%'.$keyword.'%"')
->get()->sortBy('name');
```